# Removing codeblocks ppa from Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: ppa, update-manager, code-blocks, 16.10

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I get this error when running `apt` commands. It's caused by the codeblocks ppa. I would like to remove it via terminal, because after the 16.10 update, the PPA is no longer in **Software & Updates** under **Other software**.

Comment: i found my trouble some files in /ect/apt/sources.list.d

Comment: anyone know how to delete files in their but keep the main folder?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and I used this to delete my trouble some files.

1. Run command: `apt install gksu`
2. Type `y` to install
3. Run command: `gksudo nautilus`
4. Navigate to the folder using the window opened by the precious command
5. Highlight my trouble some files mentioned in the initial question and moved to trash then emptied bin.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command in a terminal:
`sudo -i nautilus`
and open the folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Try to find the repository there and delete the file containing it. But pay attention because you are running in root mode ...

However, I have the same problem, codeblocks, under 16.10 Yakkety yak, doesn't run well and closed all frequently... grrrrr

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this through GUI. Here is the procedure:

1. browse to `/etc/apt/` then double click on **sources.list**

[image: Open sources.list which is found inside /etc/apt]

2. When Software & Updates opens click on **other software tab**. on the window down you can untick the corresponding checkboxes. you will be prompt to enter your password.

[image: Untick corresponding boxes under other sotfware tab]

3. After unticking click close, a dialog box will appear, click on reload. For this last step you need an active connection.
4. When reloading is done, you can go back in the terminal and execute you `apt-get update` command without any disturbance